# Concurrency for a class with static methods and initialization method

Tags: java, concurrency, static

How do I make the following class threadsafe?

```
public class Helper
{
    private static Map<String,String> map = null;

    public static init()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // some loading stuff
    }

    public static getMap()
    {
       if(map==null) init();
       return new HashMap<String,String>(map);
    }
}
```

My ideas so far:

1. Make getMap() synchronized.
   Problem: Makes the program slower than necessary, because syncronization is only needed at the start of the program and then never again.
2. Use a lock. The problem is that the method "isLocked" which I use here doesn't exist. So what would be the best solution?

   ```
   public class Helper
   {
    private static Map<String,String> map = null;
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static init()
     {
        lock.lock();
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // some loading stuff
        lock.unlock();
   }

   public static getMap()
   {
      synchronized {if(map==null) init();}
      while(lock.isLocked()) {Thread.wait(1);]
      return new HashMap<String,String>(map);
   }
   ```

   }

P.S.: Sorry for the second source code display problem. There seems to be a bug with using code after an enumeration.

P.P.S.: I know HashMap isn't thread safe. But that only means that I cannot *write* in parallel, *reading* shouldn't be a problem, should it?

P.P.P.S.: My final version (just the inner class), following John Vint:

```
protected static class LazyLoaded
{
    static final Map<String,String> map;
    static
    {
        Map<String,String> mapInit = new HashMap<>();
                    // ...loading...
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapInit); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You must first define what thread-safe will mean for this class. Will items be added to the map throughout the life of the program? If so, should clients that call `getMap` see those changes appear in their copies over time? If so, consider using [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap\(java.util.Map\)) instead of making a copy.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make init and getMap static, fixed now.

Comment: @David Harkness: With thread-safe I mean that the program will not crash and that getMap() does not return until the map is fully loaded. The map is only loaded once and not changed thereafter. Using Collections.unmodifiableMap is a great idea!

Comment: Nice job incorporating an unmodifiableMap + final!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delegate to a child class

```
public class Helper
{
    public static Map<String,String> getMap()
    {
         return HelperDelegate.map;
    }

    private static class HelperDelegate { 
           private static Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
           static{
                 //load some stuff
           } 

    }
}
```

Because class loading is thread-safe and occurs only once this will allow you to lazily initialize your Map.

Comment: You could do it in the outer `Helper` class as well.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet If he wants it to be lazy he wouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 3):

Simply synchronizing access to the map reference doesn't solve the problem. After the map is created, you need to synchronize operations which access and possibly modify the map's contents. An exception would be if you knew that the map is filled one time during initialization and afterwards only read operations are performed. In that case you may be fine without explicit synchronization, because your control flow takes care of that (knowing that your program's logic only allows reads after the map was initialized).

Otherwise, I would suggest you use one of the `ConcurrentMap` implementations, for example `ConcurrentHashMap` since they are relatively cheap if there is no lock contention and still provide the necessary thread safety if you do perform reads and writes during the map's lifetime.

As for the initialization, since it's a static field (so one instance only) and the cost of creating an empty map one time isn't high, I'd suggest you simply declare your map like so:

```
private static final Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
```

This way you don't need the conditional code in other methods, there are no reference visibility issues and the code gets simpler.

Comment: That map is indeed only filled once.

Answer (score 0):

Double null-check in your init method:

```
public init() {
    if (map==null) {
        synchronized(Helper.class) {
            if (map==null)
                 map = new HashMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Btw:

1. HashMap is not Thread-safe.
2. put a synchronized on the instance method is not thread-safe because you access a static variable, ie, it is a class variable, not an instance variable

Comment: Doesn't this still have the problem that my second thread can access the map after it is constructed but before it is filled? As far as I understand it, "synchronized" doesn't stop all code traversing the helper class, but only other synchronized blocks, right?

Comment: Not if you put the filling of your map inside the synchronized block.

Comment: it all depends on what you synchronize. If 2 threads synchronize on the same object (and a class is also a valid object), they cannot enter the block concurrently. This is why there is a double non-null check

Answer (score 0):

First, subsequent access to the map also needs to be synchronized, unless new HashMap() is replaced with new java.util.ConcurrentHashMap().
Then, if after initialization the variable map is never set to null again (or to any other value), then it can be declared volatile, method getMap() remain unsynchronized, ant method init() made synchronized. The method init() should one more time check if map is null.

BTW in your original code, 2 HashMaps are generated. getMap() should return variable map rather than new HashMap().

Answer (score -1):

Synchronze init and put another check for null in there

```
public class Helper
{
    private static Map<String,String> map = null;

    public synchronized init()
    {
        if(map != null)
            return;
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // some loading stuff
    }

    public getMap()
    {
       if(map==null) init();
       return new HashMap<String,String>(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. If you instantiate Helper twice, in two different threads, there could be several instantiation of the HashMap

Comment: This does not work unfortunately because my second thread invokes the copy constructor before the first one is finished with the loading.